# Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL replication?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I want to make sure that there's not a better (easier, more elegant) way of emulating what I think is typically referred to as "logical replication" ("logical decoding"?) within the PostgreSQL community.

I've got a Cloud SQL instance (PostgreSQL v9.6) that contains two databases, A and B.  I want B to mirror A, as closely as possible, but don't need to do so in real time or anything near that. Cloud SQL does not offer the capability of logical replication where write-ahead logs are used to mirror a database (or subset thereof) to another database. So I've cobbled together the following:

1. A Cloud Scheduler job publishes a message to a topic in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Pub/Sub.
2. A Cloud Function kicks off an export. The exported file is in the form of a `pg_dump` file.
3. The dump file is written to a named bucket in Google Cloud Storage (GCS).
4. Another Cloud Function (the import function) is triggered by the writing of this export file to GCS.

   1. The import function makes an API call to delete database B (the `pg_dump` file created by the export API call does not contain initial `DROP` statements and there is no documented facility for adding them via the API).
   2. It creates database B anew.
   3. It makes an API call to import the `pg_dump` file.
   4. It deletes the old `pg_dump` file.

That's five different objects across four GCP services, just to obtain already existing, native functionality in PostgreSQL.

Is there a better way to do this within Google Cloud SQL?

Comment: I cannot answer your question, just comment. If a service does not provide the features you need, in this case a managed database service, do not hobble together bandaids/workarounds that are fragile. Your question does not detail why you need a duplicate database, uptime, availability, etc. Provide more context in your question as most database scenarios have already been designed/implemented or rejected. Your question is probably more suited to one of the Stackexchange database sites.

Comment: I agree with @JohnHanley. I didn't catch the use case that lead you to duplicate database inside the same instance. B is a read only database, because you mirror A and the change in A. So, why a replica is not enough? If it's for backup, why you don't use snapshot? More context is better!

Comment: @JohnHanley You're right. Thanks for the perspective. Looking into Aiven as a potential solution.